# ngresource get error accessing properties resource

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, geojson

I have a simple factory below that request a json object with some location info. The requests works, I can see that the data is in the object. But somehow there is scope problem. I cannot access the properties of the locations object, even if I know that the object has the property and the correct array.

You can see in the code snippet below (if you look at the comments) that I cannot access some value of the object when trying to ouput to the console.

**Any idea on what could be the problem?**

```js
    .factory('Spots', function(){
        return{
            all: function($resource){
                var locations;
                var Locations =  $resource('http://localhost\\:3000/locationsd/');
                locations = Locations.get(function(){
                    console.log(locations.results[0].obj.name); // THIS WORKS -> gives me the name of the location
                });
                console.log(locations); // THIS WORKS -> log an object with a result array, etc.
                console.log(locations.results[0].obj.name); // THIS DOESNT WORK -> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
                return locations;
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: You will always get response data in the callback fucntion of `.get` method..

Comment: You can `return` from an async method...

Comment: @PankajParkar yes I understand that the callback function will wait until response data is available. But why is the returned value undefined in this case: `locations = Locations.get(function(data){ return data;}); return locations`

Comment: @user48594 you should only do this `locations = Locations.get(function(data){ return data;});` don't return location from outside of `.get` function..it will be nothing..

Answer (score 1):

This is due to it being async. To utilize $resource properly within a service, you should use promises.

```
.factory('Spots', function(){
        return{
            all: function($resource){
                var Locations =  $resource('http://localhost\\:3000/locationsd/');
                return Locations.get().$promise.then(function(res){
                    return res;
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Then when calling the function from your controller:

```
Spots.all().then(function(res){ 
   //do stuff with res here 
})
```

If you aren't aware of what promises are, read about them here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

General idea is the resource promises that it will finish eventually, and when it's done, it'll call the function you pass into its `then()`.

Comment: Why using $promise? Isn't the callback function of .get supposed to be called only when the server returns data??
And I am getting this error: _TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined_
There is obviously an error somewhere but I cant figure it out. Especially since console.log(Locations.get()) shows an object. So why cant I access the promise resource?